# Clear Output Screen from C program

Tags: terminal, xcode

I am using a Macbook Air. I used system("`cls`"); and system("`clear`").

That would not work. It displays on the output screen (xcode output screen) that the command cannot be found. I am using the C compiler, not C++.

How do I clear the output screen on Xcode? Please guide me through the steps in doing this.

Comment: This is a question more suitable for one of the programmers stack exchanges.

Comment: What do you mean by output screen, the console in Xcode or a Terminal ?

Comment: The current version of Xcode (4.5.2) has an organizer window and project windows. Which of these do you consider to be the "output screen" - feel free to edit the main question and people will see your change rather than replying in comments...

Comment: Output screen = Console screen

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I entirely follow you, however; if you are using X-Code to compile and run C programs, output (e.g. any `printf` statements) should automatically be sent to the console, like so:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   printf("Test program\n");
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Is this the 'screen' you want to clear? If so, simply building and running any program which has no console output will do so (although I'd be interested to know why you need this.)

In the example above, comment out the line with the printf statement and build and run. You'll get a clear console.

Comment: I would just like to clear the output screen on Xcode. And yes, just a simple printf example is okay. Could you also tell me how I can display the output screen on Terminal?

Comment: I use system("cls"); at school and it works fine but it does not clear the screen. Instead, it says it is not a function or it cannot be found.

Comment: I used printf("Hello World!\n"); then the line after that system("clear"); then in bold letters it displays "TERM environment variable not set." What does that mean?

Comment: Redirecting console output to the terminal is not something I've ever had call to do. However, according to an answer on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910177/can-you-redirect-log-output-of-xcode-console-to-terminal-when-running-iphone-sim] it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though it is not possible to clear the output screen with any function on Xcode. I installed Visual Studio 6 on my Windows XP and the system("cls"); function works. Thank you everyone for helping me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something that is not so system specific. Try using ANSI escape codes [to clear your screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348563/clearing-output-of-a-terminal-program-linux-c-c/23512068#23512068):

You can also try something like this, which clears the entire screen:

```
printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
```

You can include `\0333[1;1H` to be sure if `\0333[2J` does not move the cursor in the upper left corner.

More specifically:

- `033` is the octal of `ESC`
- `2J` is for clearing the entire console/terminal screen (and moves cursor to upper left on DOS ANSI.SYS)
- `1;1H` moves the cursor to row 1 and column 1